# Visual Studio / Properties / Debug / Working Directory want it permanent but don't want to check in the *.user file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, configuration-files, working-directory

The project setting Debugging / Working Directory in Visual Studio 20015 will be saved by default in the *.user file wich I don't check in in to my repo because it's user specific. Still, I would like to have something other than `$(ProjectDir)` standing there when I do a clean checkout of my project. Is there an other place to store the Working Directory besides the `*.user` file?

**Edit 1:** The original idea is that I have a solution with multiple projects and all the binaries (`dll`s and `exe`s) created end up in a folder called `bin`. If I want to debug it, I don't want to always edit the working directory again after a clean checkout.

**Edit 2:** In a post build step of every project within my solution, I copy the binaries in to the `bin` folder. If I start one of the executables from within VS, it starts them from the `$(ProjectDir)` folder, and of course not from the `bin` folder. This is why it does not find the `dll`s and why I want to set the working directory. I could change the output directory of my projects but then I get a lot of files ending up in the `bin` folder I don't want there. I will try it anyway; maybe I missed something. To be continued...

**Edit 3:** As expected, if I change the output directory to the `bin` folder, everything works fine except for some extra files that end up there and I don't want that (e.g. `*.pbo`, which would be okay, `*.iobj`, `*.ipdb`, etc.) Maybe that is the price I have to pay, but I don't like it.

**So, the question remains:** How can I have more control over which file ends up where after a build and still be able to run it from VS without changing the working dir?

Comment: The project file is the only other place, add the property.  You'll have to use a text editor, Notepad is fine.  And a comment in an easy to find place since it will confuse the bejeezus out of the next guy.  Making your program depend so critically on such an ugly global variable whose value is completely out of your control is never not a mistake btw.

Comment: No that would not be a good solution.
I edited now my question and wrote what I actually want to accomplish. Maybe you have an other idea now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The working directory should not have to be the directory that contains your DLLs. In fact, you definitely don't want that to be a requirement for running your application. Not only is it a hugely unexpected failure mode, but it could also be a potential security risk.

Put the required DLLs in the same directory as your application's executable. That's the first place that the loader will look. If necessary, use a post-build event in your library projects to copy them there.

Comment: But that is excatly the case. As I wrote all the DLLs and executables end up in the bin folder. That's the whole point.

Comment: Hmm. Then I don't understand the problem. The operating system's loader looks for DLLs in the application directory. If they're all in the bin folder, you're golden. You don't need to set the working directory. It could be anything.

Comment: Ok so there was a detail missing. I copy all the dlls and executables in an post build step in to the bin folder. If I launch one of the applications from within VS it sets the working dir to $(ProjectDir) and also starts from there. But there is only the executable. ... I update my question once more.

Comment: You are missing the point. The working directory doesn't matter. If all of the DLLs that you require are in the same folder as your EXE (bin or whatever you call it), then you won't have any problems.

Comment: You did not read right. All DLLs and executeables are within the bin folder because they where copied there by a post build step.
But the exe is of corse also inside the original output dir and that is from where VS is starting it. But there are no DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Well since no body can help me I decided that I will change the output directory to the bin folder so VS will start my applications from the correct folder.
And how I can get rid of all the extra files that don't belong there I will find a way later.